# [data-structure]: the tail pointer of cyclic queue

Tags: queue, tail, cyclic

In the implementation of Cyclic Queue, the tail pointer points to the position 1 past the last element in the queue:

```
|1|2|3|4|5| | |
 ^         ^
front      tail
```

why?

I think I can implement the Cyclic Queue with the tail pointer pointing to the very last element, not 1 past the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, indeed implement it that way. There's a certain symmetry to having the tail pointer point to the position 1 past the last element:

- `front` points to the first (oldest) used element - the next element to be read
- `tail` points to the first (oldest) unused element - the next element to be written

In either case, you need to do a bit more to distinguish between a full cyclic queue and an empty one. Some of the alternatives (including doing things your way) are discussed in the [Wikipedia article on circular buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: if tail points to the pos 1 past the last element, then when the queue is full, tail gotta point a position which is out of the index of the array (if queue implemented in array), right? Is that ok?

Comment: If it's circular, then tail should wrap around and point to position zero, not off the end of the array. Writing to a full circular queue is supposed to overwrite the oldest element (or throw an exception).

Comment: I got it, and what I'm implementing is not circular.

Comment: Oh? Then could you explain the difference between a cyclic queue and a circular queue? My answer might be a bit different if I knew.

Comment: I meant I'm implementing a simple sequential queue, not the one I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is the implementation your using's way of determining if the queue is empty or full.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#Full_.2F_Empty_Buffer_Distinction